# A lot of tags cause the 'question feed' link to extend past the screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

See:
[image: Example]

If you have a lot of long tags (eg. [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), the link extends past the end of the page, causing an excess of whitespace. In the image above, the page *should* end at the blue box, but it doesn't.

Can it be fixed to wrap, or anything else that doesn't cause it to extend?

The cause of this bug is because of `white-space: nowrap;` on `#feed-link` in the CSS, however, removing this won't be enough, because it looks kind of ugly if you do this:

[image: Removing <code>white-space: nowrap;</code>]

Any CSS experts will hopefully be able to find a solution to this... :)

If you want to see this yourself, go to [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=bug%20discussion%20feature-request%20support&mode=any) if you have [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [latest release of the beta navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) (on Stack Overflow) the wrapping issue should be resolved.

Please let me know if you see any other bugs.

Comment: Is there anyone still working on the new nav? It's been over four months since the last bug fix (this very bug) and bugs keep piling up. (From quick glance in the [bugs list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-nav+bug), you used to fix/update bugs about once a month, but not anymore. It's OK if SE decided to drop this, but we would really like to know)